# Spark MLlib - Collaborative Filtering Implicit Feed

Tags: apache-spark, recommendation-engine

So I am building an implicit feedback recommender model with Spark 1.0.0 and I am trying to follow the example they have on their collaborative filtering page:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html#explicit-vs-implicit-feedback

And I even have the test dataset loaded up which they reference in the example: 
http://codesearch.ruethschilling.info/xref/apache-foundation/spark/mllib/data/als/test.data

However when I try to run the implicit feedback model:
    val alpha = 0.01
    val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha)

(the ratings were the ratings exactly from their dataset and rank = 10, numIterations = 20) I am getting the following error:

```
scala> val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha)
<console>:26: error: overloaded method value trainImplicit with alternatives:
(ratings: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating],rank: Int,iterations: Int)org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel <and>
(ratings: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating],rank: Int,iterations: Int,lambda: Double,alpha: Double)org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel <and>
(ratings: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating],rank: Int,iterations: Int,lambda: Double,blocks: Int,alpha: Double)org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel <and>
(ratings: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating],rank: Int,iterations: Int,lambda: Double,blocks: Int,alpha: Double,seed: Long)org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating], Int, Int, Double)
val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha)
```

Interestingly, this model runs just fine when NOT doing trainImplicit (i.e. ALS.train)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example seems to be out of sync with the implementation, as there are no overloads of `trainImplicit` with four parameters -- which is what the error message is telling  you. However, if you look at the [Scala source code for ALS](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/69a57a18ee35af1cc5a00b67a80837ea317cd330/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/ALS.scala) you'll see that the three parameter overload is implemented in terms of the six parameter overload via some 'magic numbers':

```
def trainImplicit(ratings: RDD[Rating], rank: Int, iterations: Int)
    : MatrixFactorizationModel = {
    trainImplicit(ratings, rank, iterations, 0.01, -1, 1.0)
}
```

This suggests that 0.01 is a decent default value for lambda. (Perhaps good to check with someone having a deeper understanding of ML.) This may give you enough information to put together a reasonable call to the five or six parameter overload. (Of course, if you know enough to pick better values, that's great!)

For example:

```
val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01, alpha)
```

or

```
val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01, -1, alpha)
```

Finally, you may not realize that there is pretty decent [API documentaiton for ALS](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS$).

Comment: Perfect, the 'magic numbers' computation seems to work just fine!  Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: Yes 0.01 is a fine default value for lambda.